# Can't pass arrays in multidimensional array to other function using setInterval

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array named "thisIsMyContainerArray" that holds content of two other arrays. 
What I'm trying to do is check each item in the "thisIsMyContainerArray" array and log each item (in this case, two other arrays) from that array separately in the console, and do so every 5 seconds. 
So far I have the following code:

```
var thisIsMyContainerArray = new Array();
var thisIsMyArray1 = new Array('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4');
var thisIsMyArray2 = new Array('valA', 'valB', 'valC', 'valD');
thisIsMyContainerArray.push(thisIsMyArray1, thisIsMyArray2);
for (var i = 0; i < thisIsMyContainerArray.length; i++) {
    var t1 = setInterval(tester,5000);
    function tester() {
        console.log(thisIsMyContainerArray[i]);
    }
}
```

And I always get the following output in my console, every 5 seconds:

```
["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"]
["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"]
```

This is my desired result, I need to see this in the console instead of the output I mentioned earlier:

```
["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"]
["valA", "valB", "valC", "valD"]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I've been stuck on this for a few hours now and I just can't figure it out. :( I tried passing it to the tester function but then it turns out as "undefined".

Comment: couldn't you change the `setInterval()` to: `setInterval(function(){console.log(thisIsMyContainterArray[i]);});`? That'll get around the error you have.

Comment: or pass the variable 'i'. `tester(i);` `function tester(arrayIndex){console.log(thisIsMyContainerArray[arrayIndex]);}`

Comment: In reply to your first comment, that would give me the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: thisIsMyContainterArray is not defined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this - you should be able to get this working if it is not at the moment..

```
var thisIsMyContainerArray = new Array();
var thisIsMyArray1 = new Array('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4');
var thisIsMyArray2 = new Array('valA', 'valB', 'valC', 'valD');
thisIsMyContainerArray.push(thisIsMyArray1, thisIsMyArray2);

var t1 = setInterval(tester,5000);

function tester()
{
   for (var i = 0; i < thisIsMyContainerArray.length; i++) 
   {         
        console.log(thisIsMyContainerArray[i]);          
   }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks! If I remove the second loop I get the desired output. :)

Comment: yes, i was confused about JS, sorry! corrected the answer

Answer (score 1):

If I test this code in a clean environment, all it outputs is `undefined`, so its probably because the `i` variable isn't passed along, nor contained within a closure scope. Basically, there is an `i` variable somewhere in the global namespace set to 0, which is the one used.

Also, I'm not sure if you're doing more with the `t1` variable, but its being reset at every loop, so you're going to get rogue intervals.

---

If the logging is all you're after, I'd do this:

```
var thisIsMyContainerArray = new Array();
var thisIsMyArray1 = new Array('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4');
var thisIsMyArray2 = new Array('valA', 'valB', 'valC', 'valD');
thisIsMyContainerArray.push(thisIsMyArray1, thisIsMyArray2);
var t1 = setInterval(tester,5000);
function tester() {
    for (var i = 0; i < thisIsMyContainerArray.length; i++) {
        console.log(thisIsMyContainerArray[i]);
    }
}
```

If this is just a simplified example and you need the original structure with a loop and setting multiple intervals for each array, try this:

```
var thisIsMyContainerArray = new Array();
var thisIsMyArray1 = new Array('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4');
var thisIsMyArray2 = new Array('valA', 'valB', 'valC', 'valD');
thisIsMyContainerArray.push(thisIsMyArray1, thisIsMyArray2);
function tester(index) {
    console.log(thisIsMyContainerArray[index]);
    setTimeout(function() {
        tester(index);
    }, 5000);
}
for (var i = 0; i < thisIsMyContainerArray.length; i++) {
    tester(i);
}
```

Comment: How do I pass it and contain it in a closure scope?

Comment: @Magali Personally, I'd move the 'tester' function outside of the loop, give it an index parameter and a `setTimeout` at the end of the function, then call the function from within the loop. If your usecase isn't anything more than this logging, you could move the for loop in the 'tester' function. And I'd hunt down that `i` variable in your global namespace.